# How to tell ajax to run particular URL only when a pop up banner is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pop-up a feedback banner, when a particular page is loaded.
Here is the code for that.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#review_modal').modal('show');
});
```

Now I want if someone clicks any button of pop up banner, (either `Give feedback` or `No thanks`) it runs a particular URL which only does is (Never show that user feedback again)

Here is my code for that which is wrong.

```js
$(window).on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/update_feedback_status",
        });
    });
```

I am very very new to ajax, but I need this to be done as soon as possible.
How should I fix it? HO wto tell ajax that **On click means clicking on the button of that popup banner which is `#reviewmodal`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `click` event listener to the elements in popup model instead of `window`.

For example:

```html
<div id="review_modal" class="modal">
    <button>Give feedback</button>
    <button>No thanks</button>
</div>

<script>
$('#review_modal button').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/update_feedback_status",
    });
});
</script>
```